# WebGl support for android & iphone webviews

Tags: android, iphone, webview, webgl

When I went through different demos of WebGL online, I really felt it's very good for mobile GL rendering, but since it is an evolving concept it's support on mobile is questioned. As far I've found that only few android devices support it and also iPhone.

Few links i found :

1. [android](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/11/29/xperia-phones-first-to-support-webgl/)
2. [ios](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3609881?start=0&tstart=0) and many more, but the picture is not clear.

Can anyone go more deep to find the exact picture, as I want to do more 3D rendering in my app in android/ios on a webview despite native to be more dynamic at runtime?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Certain Android devices support WebGL in the default browser. For example, [Sony Xperia phones](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/11/29/xperia-phones-first-to-support-webgl/).

On other Android devices, you can try WebGL using the Firefox Mobile or Opera Mobile apps.

iOS only support WebGL through iAds, their mobile advertising platform. (It's possible to [hack your way to getting it working through a WebView](http://atnan.com/blog/2011/11/03/enabling-and-using-webgl-on-ios/), but just for a personal demo; it'll never get through the app store review process).

The quickest way to check if your device & browser can support it is to go to: http://get.webgl.org and see if you get a spinning cube.

Hopefully we'll see WebGL coming to more mobile devices soon.

** Edit ** Since posting this, WebGL can now be enabled on Chrome Beta for Android. See:

http://thenextweb.com/google/2013/01/25/google-finally-makes-it-easy-to-enable-webgl-support-in-latest-chrome-for-android-beta/

** Another Update ** It's coming to iOS8! Both to Safari and WebView:

http://www.i-programmer.info/news/86-browsers/7385-safari-on-ios8-supports-webgl-the-new-era-can-now-commence.html

Answer (score 1):

I have a Galaxy Note 2 with android 4.1. The default android browser and firefox for android supports webgl. They're both a little shaky, but you should be able to run some simple demos at least.

Firefox has a nice option for remote debugging, which I found quite useful when debugging my webgl code on android.

Comment: but my app webview will be able to render webgl?and what about ios if you have any hand on that

Comment: You can't use webgl on iOS without using a private api, meaning your app will be rejected. But it's supported, just disabled.