# Are 360 degree photos supported by Android

Tags: android, webview, panoramas, 360-degrees

I have some online Urls that Contain 360 photos, from what I can tell from these links:

- [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395245/enabling-webgl-support-for-android-webview)
- [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230088/webgl-support-for-android-iphone-webviews)

360 photos that are online can't be hosted inside a WebView at least not for Android earlier than v4. Am I correct or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of research I found out this library it is still pretty new but sure can help you start with something. I'm posting it just to save time for other searchers! cheers
[PanoramaGl-android](https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/)